# Could not synchronize CUDA stream: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch failure

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am training a set of model on different dataset to see what model perform better of every dataset. To do this I am using the following function :

```py
def train_all_models(split, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):

    reload(plt)

    model_list = [list of my models]

    model_name = [my models]

    perfs = []

    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30, restore_best_weights=True, mode='auto')

    rlr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=5, verbose=1)

    # Looping over my models
    for i, mod in enumerate(model_list):
        model = mod
        # model.summary()

        opt = optimizers.Adam()
        loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

        model.compile(loss=loss, metrics=["categorical_accuracy", Precision(), Recall()], optimizer=opt)

        print("\n===================\n", model_name[i], "\n===================\n")

        # Train my model
        #with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
        history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=100, validation_split=0.15, verbose=0, 
        callbacks=[es, rlr, TqdmCallback(verbose=0)])
        model_perf = model.evaluate(x=x_test, y=y_test)
        print("\n===================\n", str(combine), model_name[i], "perf \n", model_perf, "\n===================\n")

        perfs.append([split, model_name[i], model_perf[0], model_perf[1], model_perf[2], model_perf[3]])

        # Evaluate performances
        pred = model.predict(x_test)

        cm = confusion_matrix(tf.argmax(y_test, axis=1), tf.argmax(pred, axis=1))

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='g', ax=ax)
        ax.set_xlabel('Predicted labels')
        ax.set_ylabel('True labels')
        ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix' + split + "_" + model_name[i])
        ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['0', '1', '2'])
        ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['0', '1', '2'])
        plt.savefig("img/combine/test4/" + split + "_" + model_name[i] + "_cm.png")
        
        plt.close('all')

    # clear session
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

    return perfs
```

However after 5 to 10 datasets (with or without the use of gpu (by commenting "with tf.device('/gpu:1'):")) I get the following error :

```
raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Could not synchronize CUDA stream: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch failure
```

I dont understand where it is coming from. The first 100/150 models train well but after I always get this error. I have already tried to reinstall a new cond virtual environement but it keep getting this error. here is my config :

```
windows 10
virtual env with conda 
tensorflow 2.6.0
tensorflow-gpu 2.6.0
keras 2.8.0
cuda 11.2
cudnn 8.1
```

Comment: I found the `Tensorflow` and `Keras` version mismatch in the config specifications you mentioned. Could you please try the same code again by upgrading the `TensorFlow` and installing the same version of `Keras` as of the `Tensorflow` version. You can use this code- `!pip install tensorflow==2.8` or `!pip install --upgrade tensorflow`. Thank you.

Comment: I got the same error but even faster in my code

Comment: Okay, Could you please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements) link and verify that GPU support enabled in your system correctly.